# Slow VM installation on KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have a standard (not modified) KVM+libvirtd installed on clean Centos 6 machine with 8G of RAM and 8 cores CPU.

When I am trying to install guest centos 6 using virt-manager it takes ages to finish installation. I gave 2 cores and 3 GB of RAM to it and I can see in performance tab that it uses all 3GB of RAM permanently.

Where is a problem?

Comment: Using up all the RAM allocated for the VM is not a problem; see http://linuxatemyram.com/ . A slow installation might be a problem, but if it is, you should focus on that instead of the irrelevant RAM issue.

Comment: What can you recommend regarding slow installation?

Comment: Check CPU bottlenecks, disk i/o bottlenecks, verify you don't have any unexpected processes eating up all your RAM, attach strace to the process to see where it's hanging.. the same things you would do to troubleshoot slow ______ (fill in the blank).

Comment: Why is this titled "KVM consumes all RAM"? It sounds like it's using exactly as much RAM as you told it to use, and the issue is slow installation.

Comment: provide some details - how is the VM set up, how is the underlying storage set up, what kind of hardware it is running on

Comment: How do you installed the vm? if you are using a http source as installation media, first you need to check the download speed, in few words, you need to give more information

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue with KVM (CentOS EL 6.4) so I ran a benchmark to find out what was happening. Turns out my guest VM was running only 15% as fast as the host (bare metal OS). I had checked the prerequisites of kvm and verified my Intel processor has the VT-x (vmx) [AMD calls it svm].

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep vmx`

Why then the slow performance?? Turns out that I needed to enable VT-x in the BIOS of the system (older machine circa 2006). To verify that this was the problem, I checked to see if kernel module `kvm_intel` was running:

`lsmod | grep kvm`

Turns out that it was not running with `kvm_intel`. When I had installed my virtual machine, libvirt defined the `domain type` as `qemu`. But this should be type `kvm`. You can check:

`virsh edit your_vm_guest_domain`

... check the line at the top ...

`<domain type='qemu'>`

That was libvirt telling me it didn't detect the `kvm_intel` presence on my system and defaulted to plain qemu emulation.

When I enabled the VT-x in the BIOS, I found that I could load the `kvm_intel` module and then changed the `<domain type='kvm'>`. I executed the same benchmark again and found virtually no difference in speed between the guest VM and the host OS.

Answer (score 2):

The default disk cache mode is writethrough, which is very slow. Switch the disks to **writeback** mode and you will enjoy a very significant I/O performance boost.

Before someone complains about that: with relatively recent (CentOS 6+) libvirt/qemu/kvm versions, *writeback disks are safe* unless the guest OS does not support/activate write barriers (which are supported and enabled by any recent guest OS I can think of).

Some more information can be found [here](http://www.ilsistemista.net/index.php/virtualization/11-kvm-io-slowness-on-rhel-6.html?limitstart=0) and [here](http://www.ilsistemista.net/index.php/virtualization/23-kvm-storage-performance-and-cache-settings-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-62.html?limitstart=0)